# Can't migrate my API application through Djangorestframework

Tags: python, visual-studio, rest, django-rest-framework, django-import-export

I tried to migrate my models to the Django administration website to trake my datasets progress and modify them. However, when I insert the indicated command in the attached picture in the Visual Studio terminal. I keep getting CommandError.

[image]

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like VSCode could not identify its a django project. Try to hit `code .` from terminal and check if django modules are identified by VSCode. Also make sure the your interpreter is same as the one which is present in your virtual environment.